# What are typical values for CLmax in clean configuration?

Tags: aircraft-design

I know typical cruising CL tends to be in the range of 0,5. Maximum CL I'm guessing around 1. Does anyone know typical values?

Comment: More like 1.3 to 1.6.  Don't have a source so can't post as an answer.  If you used 1.5 you'd be in the ballpark for the vast majority of cases.

Comment: @JohnK Is this the same for planes that use supercritical airfoils? These usually stall for lower AoAs I believe.

Comment: I would say so. SC airfoils typically have laminar separation bubbles at the LE, due to the sort of squared off nose curvature, that cause them to let go from the LE instead of the TE, but the AOA this occurs is still up there. I dimly recall that the SC airfoil of the CRJ stalled at about 14 deg, and the pusher fired about a degree or two below that. because when it went the entire wing stalled at once. Frosted wings would drop the stalling AOA down to about 9-10 deg, well below pusher and there have been a number of crashes of Challengers and CRJ200s from morning frost + aggressive rotation.